# How do I deal with computations that Int64 is too big to hold?

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, overflow

I've never solved this type of problem before, so I'm not aware of the techniques used to solve it. Becuase in [my particular scenario](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fibonacci-modified) I ultimately need to print the result to the console, my guess is that I have to create some custom class that uses text to do multiplication operations. For instance, if I was dealing with an 8-bit machine and needed to compute `127^2` I would do long multiplication like you learn when you're a little kid:

```
  127
x 127
-------
  889
 254
127
-------
 2629
```

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: You may want to look at [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: There is a slight difference between the dup and this one, and that is that the dup uses `ulong` opposed to `long`. `ulong` is the single option you have before using the answers on that question.

Comment: You *can* still do your own long multiplication, if you want, or if you must target .NET 2.0 (do people still do that?). As a tip, don't do it text based, do it `uint` based (not `ulong` based, the partial products would overflow) so it does more useful math at once.